# spring data pagination return index of elements

Tags: database, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

i'm working on a spring boot project with spring data jpa and oracle database.
we need to use a native query.
the problem is the elements of content,after page 0 will return index with value like this.
this is a problem for me!

i wrote the interfce for projection,but when its method calls,can not show data!! and i forced to use String as return type!

```
    //Repository
    @Query(value = "select m.COD_USERID_PSTME as codUseridPstme " +
                "from OCM_CHARTS c " +
                "join OCM_UNITS u on u.CHRT_CHARTS_ID =c.CHARTS_ID" +
                " join OCM_POSTS p on p.UNTS_UNITS_ID = u.UNITS_ID " +
                "join OCM_POSTMEM m on m.POST_POSTS_ID = p.POSTS_ID " +
                "where  u.UNTS_UNITS_ID  in (select u.UNTS_UNITS_ID from OCM_UNITS u " +
                "start with u.COD_UNITCODE_UNTS =:unitCode " +
                "and u.CHRT_CHARTS_ID=(select c.CHARTS_ID from OCM_CHARTS c where lower(trim(c.COD_CODE_CHRT)) = lower(trim(:chartCode)) " +
                "and rownum=1) connect by prior u.UNITS_ID=u.UNTS_UNITS_ID and (:lvl=0 or LEVEL < = :lvl))" +
                "and p.STA_POSTSTATE_POST='ACTIVE' and m.STA_MEMBERSTATUS_PSTME='ACTIVE'",
                nativeQuery = true,
                countQuery = "select count(m.POSTMEM_ID) " +
                        "from OCM_CHARTS c " +
                        "join OCM_UNITS u on u.CHRT_CHARTS_ID =c.CHARTS_ID" +
                        " join OCM_POSTS p on p.UNTS_UNITS_ID = u.UNITS_ID" +
                        " join OCM_POSTMEM m on m.POST_POSTS_ID = p.POSTS_ID " +
                        "where  u.UNTS_UNITS_ID  in (select u.UNTS_UNITS_ID  from OCM_UNITS u" +
                        " start with u.COD_UNITCODE_UNTS =:unitCode " +
                        "and u.CHRT_CHARTS_ID=(select c.CHARTS_ID from OCM_CHARTS c where lower(trim(c.COD_CODE_CHRT)) = lower(trim(:chartCode))" +
                        "and rownum=1) connect by prior u.UNITS_ID=u.UNTS_UNITS_ID and (:lvl=0 or LEVEL < = :lvl))" +
                        "and p.STA_POSTSTATE_POST='ACTIVE' and m.STA_MEMBERSTATUS_PSTME='ACTIVE'")
        Page<String> getUnitUsersWithChildByChartCodeAndUnitCodeAndLevel(@Param("chartCode") String chartCode, @Param("unitCode") String unitCode, @Param("lvl") Integer level, Pageable pageable);


    //Service

    @Override
        public Page<String> getUnitUsersWithChildByChartCodeAndUnitCodeAndLevel(String chartCode, String unitCode, Integer level, Pageable pageable, String orderBy, String direction) {
            try {
                Pageable gridPageable = PageRequest.of(pageable.getPageNumber(),pageable.getPageSize(), orderBy != null ? new Sort(Sort.Direction.valueOf(direction), orderBy) : Sort.unsorted());
                return ocmPostmemRepository.getUnitUsersWithChildByChartCodeAndUnitCodeAndLevel(chartCode, unitCode, level, gridPageable);
            }catch (NoResultException e){
                systemLog.info(e.getMessage() + " " + e.getCause());
                return null;
            }
        }

    //Controller

     @PostMapping(path = "/api/v1.0/unitUsersWithChild", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
        public ResponseEntity<Page<?>> getUnitUsersWithChild(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> requestBody, @RequestParam int page, @RequestParam int size, @RequestParam(required = false, name = "orderby") String orderby, @RequestParam(required = false, name = "direction") String direction) {
            String chartCode = (String) requestBody.get("chartCode");
            String unitCode = (String) requestBody.get("unitCode");
            Integer level = (Integer) requestBody.get("level");
            Page<?> gridData = ocmPostmemService.getUnitUsersWithChildByChartCodeAndUnitCodeAndLevel(chartCode, unitCode, level, PageRequest.of(page, size), orderby, direction);

            if (!gridData.isEmpty()) {
    JSONArray((oauthDetailsService.usersOauthDetailLimitService(gridData.getContent()).getBody())));
                return new ResponseEntity<>(gridData,HttpStatus.OK);
            } else {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            }
        }


//in postman page=1 and size=5

{
    "content": [
        [
            "915817",
            6
        ],
        [
            "921850",
            7
        ],
        [
            "918637",
            8
        ],
        [
            "923357",
            9
        ],
        [
            "923103",
            10
        ]
    ],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "unsorted": true,
            "sorted": false,
            "empty": true
        },
        "offset": 5,
        "pageSize": 5,
        "pageNumber": 1,
        "unpaged": false,
        "paged": true
    },
    "last": false,
    "totalPages": 103,
    "totalElements": 512,
    "size": 5,
    "number": 1,
    "sort": {
        "unsorted": true,
        "sorted": false,
        "empty": true
    },
    "numberOfElements": 5,
    "first": false,
    "empty": false
}


//in postman page=0 and size=5
{
    "content": [
        "923145",
        "920074",
        "921101",
        "920993",
        "921151"
    ],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "unsorted": true,
            "sorted": false,
            "empty": true
        },
        "offset": 0,
        "pageSize": 5,
        "pageNumber": 0,
        "unpaged": false,
        "paged": true
    },
    "last": false,
    "totalPages": 103,
    "totalElements": 512,
    "size": 5,
    "number": 0,
    "sort": {
        "unsorted": true,
        "sorted": false,
        "empty": true
    },
    "numberOfElements": 5,
    "first": true,
    "empty": false
}
```

Comment: `but when its method calls,can not show data` - what do you mean? Is there an exception? `the problem is the elements of content,after page 0 will return index with value like this` - what do you mean by "this"? Is there a snippet of returned data? If so, add to your question please

Answer (score 0):

solved!

the problem was for using of String return type.because the String return type is unknown for spring data jpa and when it has pagination,data jpa set index for each elements!
thanks everyBody!